# Sticky footer + textarea height in percentage

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page that has a sticky footer. In the page is a textarea + a submit button. I want the textarea's height to adjust to the height of the browser's window and the button to always be right below the textarea, almost touching the footer.

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7r8zK/3/. The code:

```
<!-- Part 1: Wrap all page content here -->
<div id="wrap">
    <!-- Begin page content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
             <h1>
        Header
      </h1>

        </div>
    </div>

    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <textarea>Hello, world</textarea>
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" />Check me out</label>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <div id="push"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p>Footer</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure what to do to the form so that the textarea's height adjusts according to the window's height. Is this possible to do with just CSS (no JS)?

Comment: Why don't you use `absolute` position for your footer it will never came up or colloid [check this](http://jsfiddle.net/VivekNadar/7r8zK/7/) moreover am not sure this is your need so only am making comment here..

Comment: The jsfiddle you provided doesn't show the height of the textarea adjusting to the height of the window.

Answer (score 3):

The issue you are running into is you need to take into account the height of the header, button, and checkbox. I can only see this working if you are able to use `height: calc(100% - footer height - header height - vertical margins)` on the form and `height: calc(100% - button height - checkbox height - vertical margins)` on the textarea.

In this case, you need to know or set the height and margins on those elements. I also added `box-sizing: border-box;` to all elements to take into account padding when calculating size. You will need to account for vertical margins in your calculations.

Check this out:
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7r8zK/104/) using sticky footer from http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

I removed the push div from the html also.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
 html, body {
    height: 100%;
    /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}
#wrap {
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -100px; 
}
#wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
#footer, #wrap:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
  height: 100px; 
}
#footer {
    background: #999999;
}
#wrap > .container {
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
}

.btn, .check-box {
    height: 20px;
}

#wrap form {
    height: calc(100% - 200px); /* 200px = height of header and footer */
}
#wrap form > fieldset {
    height: 100%;
}
#wrap > form > fieldset > textarea {
    height: calc(100% - 55px); /* 55px = height of .btn and .checkbox, vertical margin of .checkbox and textarea */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you're after you could use [css calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) like so:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7r8zK/85/)**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#wrap {
    height:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#footer {
    height: 40px;
}
form {
    min-height:100px;
    height: calc(100% - 180px);
}
fieldset, textarea {
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

I also removed `<div id="push"></div>` from the html as it didn't seem to serve any purpose...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the inline code, but this works something out.

```
        </div>
    </div>

    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <textarea style="height:100%;width:100%" cols="100%" rows="100%">Hello, world</textarea>
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" />Check me out</label>
            <button type="submit" class="btn" style="float:right;">Submit</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <div id="push"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p>Footer</p>
    </div>
</div>


#wrap {margin: 0 auto -40px;}
#push, #footer {height: 40px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given 40px height to footer DIV, so either you have to apply margin, padding properties of P Tag inside footer to 0 value or have to increase height of footer, inline with that I have mentioned CSS (no change in your HTML structure) .

Here is my CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%; 
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
 /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}

#wrap {
  height: auto !important;
  height:100%;
  margin: 0 auto -40px;
  min-height: 100%;
  position:relative;    
}

.container:after {
  clear: both;
}
.container:before, .container:after {
  content: "";
   display: table;
  line-height: 0;
}
#push, #footer {
 height: 40px;
}

fieldset { height:85%; width:98%; margin:0; padding:0; position:absolute;  }
textarea {  width:96%; height:86%; margin:1%; }

#footer{ background:#f2f2f2; }
#footer p { margin:0; padding:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle for your answer.. [Fiddle Here..](http://jsfiddle.net/7r8zK/74/)

```
var height = window.innerHeight;
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var eheight = $(".page-header").height();
    $("#txt").css("height",height - eheight -90);// Here 90 resembles the height of checkbox, button and footer..
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I am looking for a non-JS solution.

Answer (score 0):

from what i understand , you want to adjust your textbox based on the data entered , but you dont want the height to exceed the window height , just till it is exactly above footer button , if this is correct , then i have used the code here :

https://raw.github.com/jackmoore/autosize/master/jquery.autosize.min.js

along with setting max height to be 180% ( this can be adjusted according to the screen you are using cause im using my laptop screen )

check the fiddle here:

```
    textarea
{
    max-height:180%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7r8zK/89/

Answer (score 0):

Let me phrase your question into plain english;
You want to have the footer always at the bottom of the screen. Where you want your textarea fill the remaining space of the form.

Let me phrase it to a little bit more "layout language"; You want the footer to be at the bottom as a static element. Where *the footer has a static height*. You want the header always be at the top where the header has a auto height, based on the content.
You want your form fill the remaining space. Where the textarea  of the form fills the remaining space of the form.

---

## Create table layout

The basic challenge for this, is that one element has an unknown height(the header). One way i can think of of doing this is using a table-layout. Where your different sections(header, form and footer) represent different table-rows:

**Html**

```
<div class="header">
   ...
</div>
<div id="content">
   ...
</div>
<div id="footer">
   ...  
</div>
```

**Css**

```
body > div {
    display: table-row;
}
```

*A [direct child selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/childselector) is used to transform all the div elements that are a direct child of the body(`#header`, `#content` and `#footer`) into a table-row.*

Where your body will act as a table:

```
body 
{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[`box-sizing`](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) is used because bootstrap uses padding on the body. This prevents the body from expanding when padding is assigned to the body.

## Get remaining space

Now you want the `#content`(which contains the form) to fill the remaining height. Because you used a table layout you can use:

```
#content {
    height: 100%;
}
```

This will automatically and dynamic fill the remaining space.

**Note about html of the button** 
An element `<button>` does not support the `type=submit` attribute, you want to use `<input>` if you want to use this attribute. Or you can just delete the attribute and use the `<button>` element.

## Second table layout

Because the principal is the same of the textarea height, you can create another table layout inside the other table layout:

```
<div id="content">
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <table id="formTable">
                <tr>
                    <td><textarea>Hello, world</textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" />Check me out
                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                     <td>
                         <input type="submit" class="btn" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

*Note that i used the plain html table tags for this. You might aswell use these elements for the previous table layout. But it depends if you rather want the html you have now.*

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7r8zK/93/)

### [With full table tags](http://jsfiddle.net/7r8zK/105/)

*Note that i used a `min-height: 300px;` on the body so the elements don't overlap each other with a too small screen. If you want to support this, you can just use a new media query to solve this.*

**additional information why this approach** 
This approach does not use any fixes or manually calculations. You will work with a table as it suppose to work.

Also `calc()` isn't widely supported, where as a table element is a basic constuct of HTML: http://caniuse.com/calc

---

Feel free to ask a question about this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking for a responsive textarea that fills the height of the window, it's actually fairly simple.

First, set your textarea to position:absolute, and then offset the top and bottom by the header and footer (+ checkbox/submit) height. This will ensure it scales proportionately.

Then set your checkbox and footer as an absolute offset from the bottom, and you are done.

http://jsfiddle.net/7r8zK/101/

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <textarea id="textarea">Hello, world</textarea>
        <div id="inputs">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" />Check me out</label>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>

#textarea {

    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    bottom:120px;
}

#inputs {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:50px;

}
```