# Sticky footer not working correctly

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky

Im trying to implement sticky footer to my site but for some reason it doesnt want to work and its pushed more than it needs to be. I've tried many "sticky footer" tutorials but there is always something not working.

Please check my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qx5Fz/1/

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#content {
    min-height: 100%;
}

#main {
    overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

#footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -40px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 40px;
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated to allow for overlapping sidebar: http://jsfiddle.net/Qx5Fz/12/

The issue you are having is using `position: fixed; height: 100%;` on the sidebar. That causes the sidebar to be 100% of the window, which will always push your footer down when it should be at the bottom of the window.

I'm using sticky footer from here: [Sticky footer + textarea height in percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952995/sticky-footer-textarea-height-in-percentage/20060126#20060126) (source: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/)

You need to put all your content inside of one div including your header. Then use this css to get the footer to work. This takes into account vertical margins, so you'll need to either incorporate any into the calcs, or just use padding.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}
#wrap {
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    /* equal to footer height */
    margin-bottom: -100px; 
}
#wrap:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
#footer, #wrap:after {
    /* .push must be the same height as footer */
    height: 100px; 
}
```

I added `top: 0` to sidebar.

Comment: But the sidebar is supposed to overlap, I wouldnt make it that way myself but it was designed this way.

Comment: I've updated the answer to still have it overlap, yet not push the footer down.

Comment: Thank you that seems to work great, hopefully Ill be able to recreate it locally. One more thing, you can notice that when you resize the window down, main text switches to the left and its under the sidebar. I know its beacuse of fixed position, it should be fixable by just changing posiiton to static right?

Comment: `Position: static` is like setting no position. That will put it above the main text. If you want it below the main text, you'll have to move the sidebar to come after the main text. I would also suggest setting height to auto when you change position.

Comment: Yeah okay, above text will be just fine, since its just for mobile viewport. Okay, thanks :)

Comment: Hopefully Im not bothering you too much, but could you help me with another thing? I updated the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Qx5Fz/15/ When you resize the window below 992px I changed the background of #main to #ccc so you can see when it happens. The #main content is stuck on the left under the #sidebar. So I also changed position to static but its now stacked, and since the viewport is still wide enough I want it to be displayed horizontally. Could you help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  #footer { position: fixed; }
```

instead of relative

Comment: I would like it to be just stuck to the bottom, not fixed. If there is no other way I will use fixed.

Answer (score 0):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Qx5Fz/8/

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    height: 40px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: I would like it to be just stuck to the bottom, not fixed. If there is no other way I will use fixed.